# How do I get an associated type from a trait implemented on HRTB referennce in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lifetime

Basically I want to have a function that can take a mutable reference to some value and potentially mutate it(by rendering an immediate mode gui and handling changes). It should also be able to take an immutable reference to same types but wrapped Cell and borrow them internally, or an mutable reference to some smart pointer that tracks changes(like changed::Cd for example), etc. So a function that can handle variety of values but also various wrappers, some might be borrowed mutably, other immutably and other passed as value, depending on type in question and whenever they have interior mutability or maybe are just Copy indexes to some global state. This function should also take an additional argument which can specify some other type-specific parameters(like range of accepted values).

I've tried to implement this using a trait `Inspect`, but I'm having troubles implementing it for the wrappers like:

```
impl<T> Inspect for &Cell<T>
    where &mut T: Inspect,
          T: Copy + PartialEq {
    type Options = <&mut T as Inspect>::Options;
    
    // ...
```

But the compiler complains that the `&mut T` in where clause is missing a lifetime. I can't define a new lifetime in `impl<'a, T>` because *the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates*. But I can use HRTBs and do it like this `where for<'a> &'a mut T: Inspect`. But now the compiler complains that the lifetime associated type is missing a lifetime. But how can Inspect::Options for &mut T from the HKTB from where clause? If I do `type Options = <for<'a> &'a mut T as Inspect>::Options;` compiler errors with: *error: expected identifier, found `&`*
Here is a complete example:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=96d41be02553b251555574ef373507c7

*I do the comparison before assignment in Cell<T> to emulate how a change-tracking pointer would be used.*

I also tried some other approaches:

Using GATs: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b771a812618d9c3f9c0f1bb9a3605f1f

Using Generic Trait: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a48cc2154c0afc58f5310125fc5b89f

Using both Generic trait and HRTBs: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d1118879a331e133b05b99910158d0ed

But they all result in lifetimes errors which I don't really have any idea how to mitigate. Especially considering the last case, it seems that a call to Inspect::inc function borrows self for longer than the function call. Even though Inspect is implemented for `&mut T` of any lifetime, it seems that because `Options` is taken from `Inspect<'a>` of named lifetime `'a`, it tries to borrow whole T for the same time, not just for the function call. If I remove Options parameter everything works as expected.

How can I solve this problem? Is this a matter of stating some lifetimes explicitly to prevent these unexpected long borrows or maybe I should try some other approach entirely?